# How do I determine the exact time of reset, due to power loss?

Tags: windows-8

The power grid where I work is not stable, and sometimes it goes down when I'm out.

I need to determine when exactly it happens. Does Windows hold this kind of information?

Comment: If you know that the power grid in your location is unstable, then strongly consider getting a UPS. Not only will a UPS prevent your system from rebooting in case there's a power glitch, any decent one (even a cheap one) should also filter the power which should help your equipment last longer. Power outages are typically accompanied by "unclean" power (fluctuating voltage and possibly frequency) around the time when the power goes out or comes back; electronics tend to not like that very much.

Comment: Do you mean without using any external equipment? External equipment could be a laptop that pings the computer in question (over Ethernet or Wi-Fi).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The most sensible solution and any decent UPS with remote management can be configured to keep a log of the power-state. Even UPS units with only  USB or serial monitoring can log via the monitoring software on the PC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Does Windows hold this kind of information?

There are two applicable events that you may find in the system event log, [EventID 6008](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_6008_Eventlog_44373.asp) and [EventID 41](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-clean).

The power loss will have occurred some time between one of these events and the previous event.

[EventID 6008](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_6008_Eventlog_44373.asp) may be more useful as it can include a timestamp (if the Persistent Time Stamp group policy setting is either enabled or not configured) showing uptime in seconds before the unexpected shutdown occurred.

Using this value together with the time stamp for the previous startup will enable you to calculate a time close to when the power outage occurred.

The previous startup can be found by looking for [EventID 6005 The event log service was started](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_6005_EventLog_45462.asp).

If your system is battery powered (for example a laptop) you can find out exactly what time the power loss occurred. See my answer [How can I find out when my laptop was last unplugged in windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1165346/337631) for a batch file which does this.

---

#### [EventID 6008 The previous system shutdown at %1 on %2 was unexpected](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_6008_Eventlog_44373.asp)

> Event Id:    6008
>
> Source:    Eventlog
>
> Description:    The previous system shutdown at %1 on %2 was unexpected.
>
> Cause 1:
>
> This event is written during startup following an unexpected restart
>   or shutdown. An unexpected restart or shutdown is one that the system
>   cannot anticipate, such as when the user pushes the computers reset
>   button or unplugs the power cord.
>
> If the Persistent Time Stamp group policy setting is either enabled or
>   not configured, system information is written to the data section of
>   this event. This information includes a timestamp that indicates the
>   computers uptime in seconds before the unexpected shutdown occurred.

---

#### [EventID 41 Kernel-Power](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-clean)

> A critical error message that resembles the following is recorded in
>   the event log:
>
> Event ID: 41
>
> Description: The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down
>   first.
>
> Note: The values for the Stop error BugcheckCode and the
>   BugcheckParameters can vary.
>
> The kernel power event ID 41 error occurs when the computer is shut
>   down, or it restarts unexpectedly. When a computer that is running
>   Windows starts, a check is performed to determine whether the computer
>   was shut down cleanly. If the computer was not shut down cleanly, a
>   Kernel Power Event 41 message is generated.
>
> An event 41 is used to report that something unexpected happened that
>   prevented Windows from shutting down correctly. There may be
>   insufficient information to explicitly define what happened. To
>   determine what may have happened and to identify a potential
>   resolution, it is important to know what the computer was doing at the
>   time just before the event occurred.
>
> If event 41 is logged because power to the computer was interrupted,
>   consider obtaining an uninterruptible power supply (UPS) such as a
>   battery backup power supply. An underpowered or failing power supply
>   may cause this behavior. For example, if you added RAM or additional
>   devices or hard disks when this problem began, the power supply may
>   cause the problem.

Comment: Checking the logs is good if the computer hasn't gone into a power-save mode like hibernation and can't log anything. You might need to set it to not hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get an exact time, as the computer doesn't know when the power loss happened. You can determine a window, from the last log entries and an Event 41 (as DavidPostill put in his answer).

Comment: Couldn't you just log the time every second and where the logs stop, the power went out.

Comment: sure, you can also add a UPS and not have the power go down at all.  However that isnt the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the computer powers on directly after, you can use one simple command to quickly find out when the computer was booted up:

```
net statistics workstation
```

This command will show a lot of information about network traffic, and at the very top, it will say: This computer is up and running since: date and timestamp.

If a UPS is present that caught the powerloss and as such the pc never stopped, this setting will not show that powerloss, which is what you are asking for. The powerloss, detected by the UPS will be shown in the eventlog if the UPS is connected using an USB cable though.

Another note, if the computer is rebooted after the powerloss, the latest reboot will be shown on this timestamp. This is not the best option therefor, but its the quickest if you are troubleshooting, which is why I decided to post an answer.

Comment: Nice. It does give the time of my last hard reset, to within 2 seconds, however the reset of the stats are all zero (except SMBs received, and Use Count). I suppose this could be because I'm using mobile tethering for my internet.

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, I think that's quite likely the case.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, you can use something like a Fluke VR1710 (Voltage quality recorder) which will give you much more precise information.

Answer (score 0):

The method described here causes the computer to periodically write the date and time to a file. If the computer goes down, there will be missing time logs.

Create a .bat file with the following lines...

```
  DATE /t >> power.log
  TIME hh:mm >> power.log
```

Then set the scheduler to run the bat program for the resolution you want i.e run once a minute, or every 10min, or whatever.

For win7 it would be...

```
1) Make sure you logged on as an administrator or you have the same access as an administrator.
2) Start->Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler
3) Action->Create Basic Task->Type a name and Click Next
4) Follow through the wizard.
```